# Changing react-router v3 to react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with migrating from react-router c3 to react-router v4. I don't know how to configure it properly.

I'm importing this:

```
import { Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then I'm setting my router in render:

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" component={Template}>
                <IndexRoute component={HomePage}></IndexRoute>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
            </Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

But only Template component is showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have nesting or Routes or `IndexRoute` and `react-router v4`, instead you can write the nested Routes within components itself, You router config will look like

```
 <BrowserRouter>
     <Route path="/" component={Template} />
 </BrowserRouter>
```

and in Template.js

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

render() {
    <div>
        {/* other content */}
        <Switch>
             <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
             <Route component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
    </div>

}
```

A `Route without a path` acts as `IndexRoute` or default route, Also Switch renders that first matched Route, so if `/contact` is rendered, `HomePage` will not be rendered

Comment: I used it and it works, but... when I'm clicking on a link to /contact path every  file, which I'm uploading is disappearing.

Comment: What do you mean ,every file that you upload is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Route path="/" component={Template}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then in **Template** component's `render` menthod nest the remaining routes

```
<div>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
</div>
```

React router v4 is major upgrade.Its completely different than v3.

You read the docs first [React Router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)